# Can you explain this System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException?

Tags: c#, multithreading, dictionary

I have following code:

```
mCommandMap[command.pId] = new System.Threading.ManualResetEvent(false);
SendCommandASync(command);
mCommandMap[command.pId].WaitOne();
```

Where `mCommandMap` is a `Dictionary<string, ManualResetEvent>` and `pId` is a string that is always created from `GUID.NewGuid().ToString()`

Now I'm in the debugger on the line that threw KeyNotFoundException. The debugger tells me there is **one item** in the dictionary and it has a key that is **exactly the same** the one I'm asking for. Go Figure.

Also this happens sporadically. Not always.

The question is, WTF?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you manipulate the `command` in multiple threads and its `pId` eventually changes.

Or, you manipulate `mCommandMap` in multiple threads without locking.

Try adding `lock()` arround the code.

Comment: Nope. The debugger says the string is in there.

Comment: Happens sporadically + things seem okay when observing the state afterwards + multithreading is involved = 99% chance you have a race condition as described.

Comment: @Kugel: then it's about the dictionary. The `Dictionary<T, U>` is not thread safe. You should not add and get items without synchronization as you can get unexpected results. Note that breaking the code into debugger may significantly change the behavior making it hard to observe.

Comment: @Mark this is not afterwards. I'm in the debugger and I can actually see the item is in there, but it still throws.

Comment: @Kugel: could you try to replace the standard `Dictionary` with `System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`?

Comment: I will try. I didn't know it existed